# Converting large result set to JSON in Java REST Web service

Tags: java, json, rest, web-services, out-of-memory

I am writing a REST API in java which basically generates a large report from database. The results from result set are passed as JSON to client. I tried converting result set to JSONArray but if result set size is large, I am getting below exception.

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
```

Is there any efficient way to do this?

Comment: when you say large, how large is the report, result set, JSONArray etc..

Comment: Result set is around 50k rows with 15 columns in it.

Comment: check using VisualVM how is the heap varying during this operation. Also check if the max heap is set very low, if so check if you can increase that.. also check any memory leaks, unnecessary loops etc..

Comment: if you can stream the response investigate using JACKSON JSON STREAMING API http://www.studytrails.com/java/json/java-jackson-json-streaming/